# Android in Navigation Drawer when I click anywhere drawer closes

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

in navigation drawer, when i push a button or anything else, drawer gets closed. What is the problem?
I search on internet but I didn't find anything that is different than my codes. Maybe there are some mistakes but I have not found them.

codes:

index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#bbb9b9b9">



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewDrawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent">
    </ListView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnMalt"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:src="@drawable/mal" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/legerin_ett"
            android:layout_weight="5.5"
            android:hint="@string/legerin_text" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnLegerint"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:src="@drawable/legerin" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnDerkevet"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:src="@drawable/derkeve" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sernavt"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="sepana tirşikê ji bo telefonên jîr"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/listViewt"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/peyameke_binivise"
        android:id="@+id/buttonPeyamBinivise"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout >
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

in main.java related codes:

```
NuceMijarAdapter adapter1 = new NuceMijarAdapter(Index.this,R.layout.list_mijar_layout,arr);
lvDrawer.setAdapter(adapter1);


private class NuceMijarAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private ArrayList<String> items;

    public NuceMijarAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_mijar_layout, null);
        }
        final String o = items.get(position);
        if (o != null) {
            String htmlText = o.replace("<a href=\"index.php?","<a href=\"http://www.tirsik.net/index.php?")
                    .replace("padding-left:8px","padding-left:1px")
                    .replace(" » ","");
            final NuceMijarIro nuce = mijarIroAction(htmlText);
            Button tvMijar = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.tvMijar);
            Button tvHejmar = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.tvHejmar);
            tvMijar.setText(nuce.mijar);
            tvHejmar.setText(nuce.hejmar);

            tvMijar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.d("url: ", nuce.link);
                    if(nuce.link.contains("index.php?mijar")) {
                        urlIndex = nuce.link;
                        if(teketin) mijarRasthatiTeketi("bnr");
                        else mijarRasthati("bnr");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would highly suggest using the new design library since you are just starting out: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is happening that you do not want to happen or what is the behaviour that you are trying to create? Please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: there is a list of buttons and when I click them the app will parse an url and list a text list. but when i click drawer just closes and app does nothing

Comment: Check my Answer Here:
[Navigation Drawer Code Update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51452874/2788786)

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem once.

I had a RecyclerView NavigationDrawer and by just moving the Navigation code to the bottom of the xml file my problem got solved.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="7dp">


<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

//some code here for the body of your activity

</RelativeLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

hope it works for you too...

Comment: This means NavigationView should be brought to front. `navigationView.bringToFront()` is equivalent to this answer

Answer (score 0):

For more explanation,

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewDrawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent">
    </ListView>
```

Is going to be your **Content** and other contents gonna be your `NavigationDrawer` actually.

**Please see how it works:**

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

**Which said:**

> the following layout uses a `DrawerLayout` with `two child views`: a
>   `FrameLayout` ***to contain the main content*** (populated by a Fragment at
>   runtime), *and a ListView for the navigation drawer*.

And use `NavigationDrawer` which that comes from with new `SupportLibrary`.