# Android Drawer navigation menu item click not working

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, navigation-drawer

Menu Item click not working I tried various things but it won't work.

Here are my code:

Home Activity:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
    private Button mBtRequest;
    private Button mBtContinue;
    private ProfileFragment mProfileFragment;
    private SetPreferences Setpref;
    private SlideUp slideUp;
    private View dim;
    private View sliderView;
    Toast toast;

    private TextView mTvDrawerName;
    private TextView mTvDrawerMobile;
    private TextView mtoolbarTitle;
    private String mfullName;
    private String mMobile;
    private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    private CompositeSubscription mSubscriptions;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Checking for first time launch - before calling setContentView()
        Setpref = new SetPreferences(this);
        if (!Setpref.IsLoggined()) {
            gotoMain();
            finish();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        mSubscriptions = new CompositeSubscription();
        initSharedPreferences();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Snackbar.make(v, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mBtRequest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_request);
        mBtContinue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_continue);
        mBtRequest.setOnClickListener(view -> slideUp());
        mBtContinue.setOnClickListener(view -> checkout());


        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        sliderView = findViewById(R.id.slideView);
        sliderView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (toast != null){
                    toast.cancel();
                }
                toast = Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
        dim = findViewById(R.id.dim);
        slideUp = new SlideUpBuilder(sliderView)
                .withListeners(new SlideUp.Listener.Events() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSlide(float percent) {
                        dim.setAlpha(1 - (percent / 100));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onVisibilityChanged(int visibility) {
                        if (visibility == View.GONE){
                           // fab.show();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .withStartGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM)
                .withLoggingEnabled(true)
                .withGesturesEnabled(true)
                .withStartState(SlideUp.State.HIDDEN)
                .build();

        Typeface myraid_bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/MyriadPro-Bold_0.otf");
        Typeface myraid_semibold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/MyriadPro-Semibold_0.otf");

        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        mTvDrawerName = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.nav_user_name);
        mTvDrawerMobile = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.nav_mobile_number);
        mtoolbarTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        mTvDrawerName.setText(mfullName);
        mTvDrawerMobile.setText(mMobile);

        mTvDrawerName.setTypeface(myraid_bold);
        mTvDrawerMobile.setTypeface(myraid_bold);
        mtoolbarTitle.setTypeface(myraid_semibold);
        mBtRequest.setTypeface(myraid_bold);
        mBtContinue.setTypeface(myraid_bold);
    }


    private void initSharedPreferences() {
        mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        mfullName = mSharedPreferences.getString(Constants.FULLNAME,"");
        mMobile = mSharedPreferences.getString(Constants.MOBILE,"");
    }


    private void gotoProfile(){
        if (mProfileFragment == null) {
            mProfileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
        }
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentFrame,mProfileFragment,ProfileFragment.TAG).commit();
    }

    private void gotoMain(){
        Setpref.setIsLoggined(false);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void slideUp(){
        slideUp.show();
    }

    private void checkout(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void logout() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(Constants.MOBILE,"");
        editor.putString(Constants.TOKEN,"");
        editor.putString(Constants.FULLNAME,"");
        editor.apply();
        gotoMain();
    }

    private void showSnackBarMessage(String message) {
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout),message,Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_my_addresses) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_orders) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_refer) {

        }  else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
           logout();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

activity_home_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_my_addresses"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_location_on_white_24px"
            android:title="My Addresses" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_my_orders"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_history_white_24px"
            android:title="My Orders" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_refer"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_record_voice_over_white_24px"
            android:title="Refer &amp; Earn" />
    </group>

    <group
        android:id="@+id/menu_bottom"
        android:checkableBehavior="none">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_white_24px"
            android:title="Logout" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

nav_header_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Aashish Kaushik"
        android:id="@+id/nav_user_name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nav_mobile_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="9910454530"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <FrameLayout
        android:alpha="0"
        android:id="@+id/dim"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/dimBg" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />

    <!-- The Fragment -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

When I try to view activity_home.xml as a design it will not showing left drawer but when I install the app on device it will show the left drawer on click but when I click on any time it will not showing check able box and not working.

Answer (score 3):

Update These lines of code works for me.. after update clean and rebuild Project.

```
  NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.bringToFront();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution to address this issue. You can just link your HomeActivity methods to the menu items (whichever you want to). Now just create your methods and go to the menu layout. In the menu layout just add the android:onClick inside the item tag and put the particular method name inside it. And you are done. Let me know if this was useful.